# Google Sheets API: The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to read the document from the cron:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<sheet_id>?key=<api_key>`

My document is available to anyone with the link.

---

```
My #1 key settings:    
Application restrictions:

 - IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) - I added my external IP address.
 - API restrictions - none
```

---

```
My #2 key settings:
Application restrictions:

 - IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) - I added my external IP address.
 - API restrictions - Google Sheets API
```

---

```
My #3 key settings:
Application restrictions:

 - IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) - I added my external IP address.
 - API restrictions - Google Sheets API, Google Drive API
```

---

```
My #4 key settings:
Application restrictions:

 - IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) - none
 - API restrictions - Google Sheets API
```

---

```
My #5 key settings:
Application restrictions:

 - IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) - none
 - API restrictions - Google Sheets API, Google Drive API
```

---

```
My #6 key settings:
Application restrictions:

 - IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) - none
 - API restrictions - none
```

---

When I try to open a document with each key, I get a 403 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The same error occurs when using the API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).

At the same time, the document itself opens successfully from a link from any computer and from any browser even to unauthorized users.

This problem began on July 9 at 09:35 PM (UTC+0).

Prior to this error, I successfully received data from the document using the `#1 key settings`.

**Update:**

I found another strange nuance: on all other documents there is no such problem. An error is observed on one particular document. I compared the access settings with others - they are identical.

**Update 2:**

I tried to copy the table and open it via API - the error was the same.
An hour later I tried again - it all worked.

Comment: I have the same problem. It worked today in the morning but got the error this afternoon after no change. Maybe it's a Google issue.

Comment: This issue is driving me mad, I'm glad I found this post. Any official acknowledgement from Google about this?

Comment: Same situation for me today. Tried generating new API keys and no luck. Hopefully it gets ironed out soon.

Comment: We are having the same issue, publicly available spreadsheet but PERMISSION_DENIED from the API... Must be something on Google's side

Comment: Is there some way to make an official bug report to Google?

Comment: Issue has been posted here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111465512

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. If anyone is updated with a solution can they please share?

Comment: It just worked on my public sheet!

Answer (score 2):

After seeing [HoverPhoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461624/hoverphoenix) comment, I change access of My sheet to ** Anyone with link** on **Viewer** mode.

[image: Example Access Image]

After changing the access it is working properly. If Data security is the concern then the best option is to use OAuth 2.0 Client IDs as credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As @thinktwice said it is suggested to turn on the `Anyone with the link` option in the sheet.

I was using python and this `created_spreadsheet.share('', role='reader', type='anyone')`  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

API key is for getting public spread sheets, if you want to get private ones, consider using a service account